# VBOs with vertecies as vector<float4>

Tags: opengl

Attempting to pass a VBO vertex and color-data from a `std::vector<float4>` where the `float4` is similar to a CUDA float4 (object with x,y,z,w).

```
int createVertexArrayObject(std::vector<float4> vertex_buffer_data, 
                        std::vector<unsigned int> index_buffer_data, 
                        std::vector<float4> color_buffer_data){

float* vertex_data = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&vertex_buffer_data[0]);

unsigned int vertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

unsigned int vertexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);

glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    vertex_buffer_data.size()*sizeof(float4),
    vertex_data,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
   (...)
  }
```

This is what I am working with in terms of passing the data to the VBO. However, nothing renders. 
Am I calculating the size correctly, and am I providing the correct reference to the first element in the structure?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In which context do you use that? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . What is `float4`? Do you mean `float[4]`? If you have `std::vector<float4> buffer`, then the size of the buffer in bytes is `buffer.size()*sizeof(*buffer.data())` and a pointer to a consecutive array containing the data is returned by `buffer.data()`

Comment: The code snippet of the question will work. The issue is not in this code, it has to be somewhere else. (Side note, you should pass the parameters by reference and not by value to the function - e.g. `std::vector<float4> &vertex_buffer_data`)

Comment: What is the exact type declaration of `float4`? Is it a `class` with a `virtual` method or destructor?

Comment: This is parts of an assignment, so I am working with some provided types. This is float4 https://pastebin.com/rVxUfLsN

Comment: As far as I can tell that's not the issue. Is `sizeof(float4)` == 16?

Comment: Yes, sizeof(float4) == 16

Comment: What are the `w` components of your coordinates 0,0 or 1,0? - see the answer.